# Does western dressing reaveling much of women on net breaks wudu?

Tags: wudu

This question has confused me a lot recently. I have facebook pages that sometimes show women too much, like fitness pages, celebrity pages (showing legs or cleavage of some female celebrities) or fitness pages which are of guys but show women too in tights or shorts or swimwear. So does this kind of images break your wudu? Also, I have an allergy between my thighs and pubic area and I scratch it to get rid of the irritation, and it almost makes me feel like I'm rubbing my front private part. So does this break the wudu too?

Answer (score 1):

Bismillah.

There are only certain actions that break wudu. The first part of what you have mentioned is not one of them. Although, touching of the penis does nullify wudu. The actions that break wudu are:

1 – Any discharge from the front or back passage (urine, stools, wind, etc.), except for wind emitted from a woman’s front passage – that does not break wudu.

2 – Emission of urine or stools from anywhere other than the urethra or anus.

3 – Losing one’s mind, which may mean losing it altogether by losing one’s mental faculties, which is insanity, or by losing it temporarily for a certain length of time for some reason such as sleep, unconsciousness, intoxication, etc.

4 – Touching one’s penis, because of the hadeeth of Basrah bint Safwaan, who heard the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) say:

> “Whoever touches his penis, let him do wudoo’.” (narrated by Abu
>   Dawood, al-Tahaarah, 154. al-Albaani said in Saheeh Sunan Abi Dawood,
>   no. 166, it is saheeh).

5 – Eating camel meat, because of the hadeeth of Jaabir ibn Samurah, who said that a man asked the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him),

> “Should we do wudoo’ after eating camel meat?” He said, “Yes.”
>   (Narrated by Muslim, al-Hayd, 539).

Comment: #3 is disputable as it has no solid evidence.  Sleep doesn't break wudhu.

Comment: @Sayyid "Sleep invalidates wudoo’ except light sleep in the case of one who is sitting or standing. This is the view of the Hanbalis. See al-Insaaf, 2/20, 25". While I agree that there has been no hadith to support it, there has been no hadith stating the contrary either. And, most scholars agree with this. http://islamqa.info/en/36889. Jazak Allah Kheiran