# Does touching my wife break Wudu (ablution) ?

Tags: sharia, wudu

If a man touches his wife while he is in the state of wudu, will he need to wudu again?  Is it same if wife is in the state of her periods ?

Comment: There was a similar question posted: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12844/does-western-dressing-reaveling-much-of-women-on-net-breaks-wudu/12867#12867. Only a few actions cause the breaking of a wudu, mentioned in the link.

Comment: Yes, according to the general wording of the Quran, coming in contact with any woman breaks the wudhu.

Comment: This is a matter in which the scholars disagree. As written, it's merely attracting opinions rather than useful practical answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

walecum assalam,

No. according to scholars, it does not break wudu.

For detailed answer, please consult this website: http://islamqa.info/en/769